# How to use many

Tags: translation, usage

ワザに必要なエネルギーよりも多く「水」エネルギーがついている時、多い「水」エネルギー1つにつき、10ダメージを追加する。

I'm having trouble understanding よりも多くand 多い, Is it literally saying 'more than many needed to use' and 'many energy'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of the first 多く is correct, "more than necessary for (using) the ワザ". The second 多い is indeed tricky, but in this context it obviously means "surplus/excess".

> ワザに必要なエネルギーよりも多く「水」エネルギーがついている時、
>   When [it] has more water energy than what is necessary for the ワザ,
>
> 多い「水」エネルギー1つにつき、10ダメージを追加する。
>   Inflicts additional 10 damage per 1 surplus water energy.

You can think ワザに必要なエネルギーよりも is omitted before the second 多い. In other words, this `多い「水」エネルギー` is not simple "much energy" but "more-than-necessary-to-use-the-ワザ energy". It can be understood in the context, but 余剰の or 余った would've been more concise.

> 余剰の「水」エネルギー1つにつき、10ダメージを追加する。

Answer (score 0):

1. 私は**多く**の本を持っている。*I have many books*.
2. 私はあなた**よりも多く**の本を持っている。 *I have more books than you*.
3. 私はあなた**より多く**の本を持っている。 *I have more books than you*.

1 and 2 are apparently different from each other.
However, although the nuance is slightly different between 2 and 3, they are the same when translated into English using "google translation".

I examined [here](http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/search_result) whether "よりも多く" and "より多く" are interchangeable. According to my brief examination I can see that in most cases they are  not interchangeable. So what is the difference? I will investigate the difference further in order to explain it clearly. The answer will be made after the survey is over.